# Magento - Multilanguage store view

Tags: language

I need to create a multilanguage site. I created more store view with code : en, it and es, but when i select a different store  are not translated texts. But it's okay if imposed System -> Configuration -> General -> Local option, the text are translated in that case, but if a "runtime" change the store does not change language.

I hope to get advice, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by "runtime change"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have set up each store view, you have to set the language for those. You can do that in `System > Configuration > General > Locale`. But, you have to do it for each store view by changing to that store view in the drop-down, then set that language for that store view. Make sure to refresh the indexes and cache afterward. May have to clear your cookies as well.